# In Groovy SwingBuilder, how do I attatch a closure to a JTable that fires when a cell is selected?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, jtable, closures

I have a JTable being constructed via Groovy's SwingBuilder.  I'd like to attach a closure to the table that fires when a cell is selected, but I can't seem to find the right hook.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in groovy, but when inside the table element of the swingbuilder, you could use the [Groovy way to implement interfaces](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces). This works because ListSelectionListener only has one method.

```
table(id: 'myTable') {
    myTable.selectionModel.addListSelectionListener({evt->
            println("selection changed")
        } as ListSelectionListener)
    }
```